# Questions on Methods from Rails Presenters Tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Question about a couple of methods that I saw in this tutorial: https://richonrails.com/articles/rails-presenters

In particular:

```
module ApplicationHelper
    def present(model, presenter_class=nil)
        klass = presenter_class || "#{model.class}Presenter".constantize
        presenter = klass.new(model, self)
        yield(presenter) if block_given?
    end
end
```

And

```
class BasePresenter < SimpleDelegator 
    def initialize(model, view)
        @model, @view = model, view
        super(@model)
    end

    def h 
        @view 
    end

end
```

How does the `present` method work? I'm pretty confused about its arguments parameters, ie, `model, presenter_class=nil` along with the whole method.

And I'm also very confused about `model, view` arguments as well, and where/what is `super(@model)` method?

Any information that can explain those methods would be so immensely helpful because I've been staring at it for the past while wondering how the heck they work.

Answer (score 0):

I'll give this a shot.

The `present` method accepts two parameters, a model, and a presenter class.

The `presenter_class = nil` means that `presenter_class` is an optional parameter, and will be set to `nil` if a variable is not passed as that parameter when the method is called.

I've added comments to the code to explain what's happening step by step.

```
# Define the Helper (Available in all Views)
module ApplicationHelper
    # Define the present method, accepts two parameters, presnter_class is optional
    def present(model, presenter_class=nil)
        # Set the presenter class that was passed in OR attempt to set a class that has the name of ModelPresenter where Model is the class name of the model variable
        klass = presenter_class || "#{model.class}Presenter".constantize
        # ModelPresenter is initialized by passing the model, and the ApplicationHelper class
        presenter = klass.new(model, self)
        # yeild the presenter if the rails method block_given?
        yield(presenter) if block_given?
    end
end
```

[Here's another question explaining how yield works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19020601/understanding-yield-in-rails-presenter)

[Here's some more info on the rails constantize method](http://apidock.com/rails/String/constantize)

The `BasePresenter` inherits from the SimpleDelegator class [(documentation)](http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_inheritance.html).

```
class BasePresenter < SimpleDelegator 
    def initialize(model, view)
        # Set the instance variables @model and @view as the two parameters passed to BasePresenter.new
        @model, @view = model, view
        # calls the inherited SimpleDelegator initializer with the @model parameter
        super(@model)
    end

    # An instance method that returns the @view variable that was set on initialization
    def h 
        @view 
    end

end
```