# In Ruby, how does one verify the identity of a Struct?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, struct, self, presenter

I've been trying to make sense of the class of `self` in the `present` method that Ryan Bates used in his Presenters RailsCast ([#287 Presenters from Scratch (pro) - RailsCasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/287-presenters-from-scratch?autoplay=true)). In the video, Ryan says, 'Self is the template object which has all the helper methods we want to access', but I wanted to know the class for this object. After reading a range of blog posts, SO threads, and Ruby docs, I'm starting to think that `self` is a kind of Struct, but I don't know how to confirm this notion.

My questions are: **1)** In the `present` method below, is `self` a [Struct](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Struct.html)?, and **2)** How does one verify that something is a Struct?

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def present(object, klass = nil)
    klass ||= "#{object.class}Presenter".constantize
    presenter = klass.new(object, self)
    yield presenter if block_given?
    presenter
  end
end
```

I'm asking this because I don't have much experience working with  `Struct` classes and when I stick `binding.pry` in the middle of the method above and try to get the name of the class for `self`, I end up with more questions.

- When I enter `self.class`, I get, `#<Class:0x007fb64f696268>` *I wondered if getting `Class` here might indicate that I have a `Struct`, but I couldn't find any documentation that confirmed this*
- When I enter `self.class.class`, I get `Class`
- When I enter `self`, I get an extensive object that starts with the lines of code of code listed below

  ```
  @ line 16 ApplicationHelper#present:

  14: def present(object, klass = nil)
  15:   klass ||= "#{object.class}Presenter".constantize
  16:   binding.pry
  17:   presenter = klass.new(object, self)
  18:   yield presenter if block_given?
  19: end

  [1] pry(#<#<Class:0x007fb64f696268>>)> self
  => #<#<Class:0x007fb64f696268>:0x007fb64f6948f0
  @_assigns={"marked_for_same_origin_verification"=>true},
  @_config={},
  @_controller=
    #<PostsController:0x007fb64f6762d8
     @_action_has_layout=true,
     @_action_name="show",
     @_config={},
     @_db_runtime=0,
     @_lookup_context=
      #<ActionView::LookupContext:0x007fb64f6760d0
        @cache=true,
        @details=
          {:locale=>[:en],
          :formats=>[:html],
          :variants=>[],
          :handlers=>[:raw, :erb, :html, :builder, :ruby]},
        @details_key=#<Concurrent::Map:0x007fb64f697938 entries=0 default_proc=nil>,
        @prefixes=["posts", "application"],
        @rendered_format=:html,
        @view_paths=
          #<ActionView::PathSet:0x007fb64f675fe0
  ```

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25874089/8481019) was helpful in explaining how a Struct works, but doesn't explain how one can confirm that they have a Struct.

Initially, when I started dissecting the `present` method, I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36274384/8481019) to be helpful. However, I was thrown off by the comment, saying that the "ModelPresenter is initialized by passing the model, and the ApplicationHelper class", since ApplicationHelper is a module.

Comment: Keep in mind that you're touching on Rails internals here and the Rails internals are not exactly simple, straightforward, or well documented. It is very confusing and takes a long time to cut through all the magic and get your head around it.

Comment: Indeed! I don't want to get lost in the weeds, but I also want to spend some some time challenging my own wrong assumptions, so that I can cut through the magic eventually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Summary

Use `is_a?(Struct)`

#### Explanation

A struct is a constructor for an anonymous class:

```
struct_class = Struct.new(:foo)
# => #<Class:0x007fa7e006ea98>
```

You can check that an instance of the anonymous class is a struct like so:

```
inst = struct_class.new
inst.class.superclass
# => Struct
```

However [Object#is_a?](https://apidock.com/ruby/Object/is_a%3F) checks the parent class *as well as* superclasses:

```
inst.is_a?(Struct)
# => true
```

You can see the same behavior in the following arbitrary example:

```
# inherits from String
anon_class = Class.new(String) 

inst = anon_class.new
# => ""

inst.class == String
# => false

inst.is_a?(String)
# => true
```

Comment: The thing is, when I submit `self.is_a?(Struct)`, I get `false`.

Comment: But, `self.class.superclass` returns `ActionView::Base`... Finally, that gets me to closer to what I was looking for. Thank you, @max-pleaner

Comment: @GinnieHench That suggests that `Class.new(ActionView::Base) do ... end` was used to dynamically create a subclass of `ActionView::Base` with some extra methods and what not specific to the view in question.

Comment: Hmm, I haven't called any methods like that within my app, but I am calling the `present` method within erb in a view. By running `self.class.ancestors` in pry, I see a bunch of ActionView::Helpers listed, along with other Rails modules, so I can see how `self` "has all the helper methods we want to access" that Bates mentions, but I'm still not 100% sure what to call self.... Given that `self.is_a?(Object)` returns true and `self.class.is_a?(Class)` returns true, I have to settle on accepting that `self` is an object from the `Class` class.

Comment: Rails will often create anonymous classes when it needs an isolated container for a bunch of stuff (such as a view). You're not doing it, Rails is. And then Rails will mash a bunch of modules (such as view helpers) into the anonymous class and copy instance variables from the controller to the view instance.

Comment: Little tidbit: Using `case object` and `when Struct` also works.